¿Cómo generar una imagen Docker con Vite, TypeScript y PNPM?
Hola soy nuevo en el entorno de docker, así que como proceso de aprendizaje decidi generar una imagen docker con PNPM, vite, typescript pero al momeneto de lanzar la imagen me arroja error, quisiera su amable ayuda.
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN apk add --no-cache dos2unix build-base python3

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN dos2unix package.json pnpm-lock.yaml

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["pnpm", "dev"]

El error que me lanza al ejecutar la imagen es:

Desconozco si el sistema operativo pueda afectar en estos casos para crear la imagen, más sin embargo mi sistema operativo es Windows.
Adicional ¿qué debería tener encuenta si quiero generar un docker compose?

Encontré algunos tutoriales. Espero que te sirvan https://dev.to/code42cate/how-to-dockerize-vite-44d3 https://thedkpatel.medium.com/dockerizing-react-application-built-with-vite-a-simple-guide-4c41eb09defa
